# Importing LLMChain from langchain root module is no longer supported

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, openai-api

I am trying to create an adventure game with AI, based on this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nhYcTh6vw9A&t=966s

However, I am getting error message like this:

> Importing LLMChain from langchain root module is no longer supported.

This is the code:

````py
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
from langchain.memory import CassandraChatMessageHistory, ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain import LLMChain, PromptTemplate
import json

cloud_config= {
  'secure_connect_bundle': 'secure-connect-choose-your-own-adventure.zip'
}

with open("choose_your_own_adventure-token.json") as f:
    secrets = json.load(f)

CLIENT_ID = secrets["clientId"]
CLIENT_SECRET = secrets["secret"]
ASTRA_DB_KEYSPACE = ""
OPENAI_API_KEY = ""

auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
cluster = Cluster(cloud=cloud_config, auth_provider=auth_provider)
session = cluster.connect()

message_history = CassandraChatMessageHistory(
    session_id="anything",
    session=session,
    keyspace=ASTRA_DB_KEYSPACE,
    ttl_seconds=3600
)

message_history.clear()

cass_buff_memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
    memory_key="chat_history",
    chat_memory=message_history
)

template = """..."""

prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["chat_history", "human_input"],
    template=template
)

llm = OpenAI(openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY)
llm_chain = LLMChain(
    llm=llm,
    prompt=prompt,
    memory=cass_buff_memory
)

choice = "start"

while True:
    response = llm_chain.predict(human_input=choice)
    print(response.strip())

    if "The End." in response:
        break

    choice = input("Your reply: ") ```

I tried to import libraries and expected them to work
````

Answer (score 2):

As of Oct 2023, the `llms` modules are all organized in different subfolders such as:

```
from langchain.llms import GPT4All, OpenAI
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.chains.prompt_selector import ConditionalPromptSelector
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferWindowMemory
```

Answer (score 1):

according to [this article](https://linuxhint.com/use-langchain-llmchain-function-python/), i think langchain moved most of its chains into a directory of its own, called chains. so using `from langchain.chains import LLMChain` should work

Comment: I changed the import code :  from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
from langchain.memory import CassandraChatMessageHistory, ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
import json                                                          
But it also gave me another error saying this : TimeoutError: timed out.                
with a bunch of code above. I got my database running tho

Comment: it's good that the database is running.

btw, where did you get the timeout error? cause it could be caused by a lot of things

Comment: I don't know myself since im a noobie xD but it says session timed out and repeating this message over and over again

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve / quieten a related warning of "importing llm_cache from langchain root module is not supported" by adding this line to my code:

```
from langchain.globals import set_llm_cache, get_llm_cache
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using following command to import `LLMChain` in the code

`from langchain.chains.llm import LLMChain`

This is the class in which `LLMChain` is defined. To know more about it check this [link](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/chains/langchain.chains.llm.LLMChain.html#langchain.chains.llm.LLMChain)